# How can I save the contents of an SWT StyledText widget as HTML?

Tags: java, html, swt, styledtext

Is there an easy way to take the contents of an SWT StyledText widget and save it as HTML, and then conversely take back the saved HTML to load it into the StyledText?

Comment: I don't think this is included in SWT, nor is it a trivial task. You will probably need to run through all the styles and add tags manually. I like this idea though; if you find some free time, you might want to start a project. I'd be interested to join in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this [SWT RichTextEditor](http://www.dugaldmorrow.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=24&Itemid=44) does it. Source code is not available, however; it also does not seem to support multiple fonts in the same StyleText widget.

Comment: The link is dead, but could this be the same thing? https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/rich-text-editor

Comment: I don't know, it was too long ago for me to remember what the original link featured.